# Laravel dd() equivalent for Cake PHP

Tags: php, laravel, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I would like to know if there is an equivalent method to laravel method dd() for Cake PHP.
If you don't know, dd() dump the given variable and end execution of the script.

Thanks you.

Comment: debug($var); exit;

Comment: It worked perfectly, thank you !

Comment: I would make a PR to get dd() into the core, I once tried, but with more voices this might succeed.

Comment: Until then you can use the [Tools Plugin](https://github.com/dereuromark/cakephp-tools/blob/master/config/bootstrap.php#L62) which contains them, as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a `prd()` function into bootstrap.php

```
function prd($var)
{
    pr($var);
    die;
}
```

source: http://debuggable.com/posts/make-your-life-easier-with-these-five-cakephp-quicktips:48170ee5-0cc0-4815-af60-7c264834cda3

You could also add it to cakephp/app/Config/helpers.php

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/larapack/dd

Very straightforward to install via Composer.

Answer (score 0):

Jus use dump($var);

After that you can stop  the execution with exit;

Comment: I use it all the time